# Mysql select totals and names

Tags: mysql

List the customer first name, last name, and total amount spent (Note: the amount spent is the order subtotal + the tax + the cost to ship from the tblorder  table).

i have this code(but the values all come out the same:

```
Select CONCAT(firstname, ' ' ,lastname) as name, sum(ordersubtotal + ordertax + ordershipcost) as AmountSpent
From tblorder,tblcust
group by name
```

[image: my queries]

Comment: Try putting a join condition between your tables.  As a rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join`.

Comment: idk what to join is it name and custid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Select CONCAT(firstname, ' ' ,lastname) as name, sum(ordersubtotal + ordertax + ordershipcost) as AmountSpent
From tblorder a
inner join tblcust b ON a.custId=b.custId
group by name;
```

YOu did not define on what you are joining the tables.

In your code style that would be:

```
Select CONCAT(firstname, ' ' ,lastname) as name, sum(ordersubtotal + ordertax + ordershipcost) as AmountSpent
From tblorder a,tblcust b
where a.custId=b.custId
group by name;
```

(Both should give the same result)